# Where can I find a recent version of the Zend Debug Protocol?

Tags: php, eclipse, eclipse-pdt, zend-debugger

I am interessted in using the Zend Debugger. The newest and only document about the Zend Debug Protocol seems to be this http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/documents/PDT%20-%20Debug%20Protocol.pdf document from 2006. Aptana and PDT are using Zend Debug Protocol, or at least have it as an option. Any idea where I can find a more recent version of this file or another file where I can read about the debugging protocol? Any hints would be great

Answer (score 0):

i'm afraid your best option is studying the source[[1](http://wiki.eclipse.org/CVS_Howto), [2](http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/index.cgi/org.eclipse.pdt?root=Tools_Project)]. you can find the protocol implementation (de/serializations of IDebugRequest/ResponseMessages) in [org.eclipse.php.debug.core/src/org/eclipse/php/internal/debug/core/zend/debugger/messages](http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/index.cgi/org.eclipse.pdt/plugins/org.eclipse.php.debug.core/src/org/eclipse/php/internal/debug/core/zend/debugger/messages/?root=Tools_Project). good luck :)